Android Enterprise: The Zero-touch portal doesn't have the Owner user. (I accidentally put down the permission into Admin)
I'm trying to use the Zero-touch portal for Android Enterprise.
After several tests, I accidentally lowered the permission of the only user to 'Admin' permission.
In short, right now the account is working without the Owner user.
And it's quite confusing that the Portal is letting it happen.
Now I don't have Owner permission in my account.
Is there any way to add a new Owner account to the Portal,
or change the permission back to 'Owner'?
